# Rails 5 - strong parameters: array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I'm sending these Parameters on my request:

```
{"rss":[{"rss":"http://sneakernews.com/feed/","type":"2"},{"type":"4","rss":"https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/-/index.rss"}]}
```

On my controller I'm doing this:

```
rss = rss_params[:rss]

def rss_params
    params.permit(:rss => [:type, :rss])
end
```

But I'm always getting this:

```
["#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007faf809281a0>", "#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007faf700b75a8>"]
```

How can I retrieve the hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 5 just iterate over them and then permit each hash

```
params.require(:rss).map do |p|
  p.permit(:rss, :type)
end
```